# Git Aliases not working

Tags: linux, git, terminal, alias, git-config

I have specified certain aliases in the `.gitconfig` file located in `/home/myUser/.gitconfig` as below (I am pasting the entire file settings):

```
[user]
    name = myName
    email = myEmail@email.com
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    safecrlf = true
[push]
    default = simple

[alias]
    co = checkout
    ci = commit
    st = status
    br = branch
    hist = log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
    type = cat-file -t
    dump = cat-file -p
```

I am having a problem specifically with that `hist` alias. Sometimes I get the desired output when y execute de `git hist` (I mean the format specified in the `.gitconfig` for the `hist` alias); and some other times it is not recognized. I tried restarting the terminal an the same happens: sometimes it works and some other times don't.

Would appreciate any help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks and works fine for me!

Comment: Could you describe an actual case where `git hist` did not work as expected?  Are you working off [this tutorial](https://githowto.com/aliases) ?

Comment: I simply type `git hist` and sometimes works as expected and some other times dont. I am following a different tutorial i found on the internet "Git Inmerssion" but apears to ve very similar